# Why does apache.commons.dbcp2 connection pool gets socket error when trying to create a new connection?

Tags: connection-pooling

I am experiencing a error randomly in production.
This happens when we have a surge in load and application tries to do a high volume of inserts.

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:205)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:836)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:434)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:102)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1413)
```

Connection pool should be able to create new connection if it exhausts the existing connection.

Max limit of connection pool is 100

Min  is 8.

Why is the pool not able to create connection ?

In my research I found people suggesting to use this parameter

```
oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout
```

But I am not convinced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through logs and Oracle documentation, this error happens when oracle is refusing connection. The reasons why this was happening in our case was because the server was overloaded(it did not ran out of connections) and was not accepting any new request.